# Cats Free Monad based algebras composition

Tags: scala, scala-cats, free-monad

Suppose I've got the following algebra for working with file system:

```
sealed trait Fs[A]
case class Ls(path: String) extends Fs[Seq[String]]
case class Cp(from: String, to: String) extends Fs[Unit]

def ls(path: String) = Free.liftF(Ls(path))
def cp(from: String, to: String) = Free.liftF(Cp(from, to))
```

And the following interpreter for the algebra:

```
def fsInterpreter = new (Fs ~> IO) {
  def apply[A](fa: Fs[A]) = fa match {
    case Ls(path) => IO(Seq(path))
    case Cp(from, to) => IO(())
  }
}
```

Now suppose I want to build another algebra that uses the first one. E.g.:

```
sealed trait PathOps[A]
case class SourcePath(template: String) extends PathOps[String]

def sourcePath(template: String) = Free.liftF(SourcePath(template))
```

The next thing I want to write an interpreter for `PathOps ~> IO` which would do something like this:

```
for {
  paths <- ls(template)
} yield paths.head
```

In other words my interpreter for `PathOps` should call into `Fs` algebra.

How do I do that?

Comment: There's a full example of this exact problem in the cats docs: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html (section: Composing Free monads ADTs.)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that section answers my question. It does explain how to compose 2 mutually independent ADTs when building a program. It doesn't however cover a case when the interpreter for one ADT relies on the other ADT

Comment: @AlexandrAntonov Could it be that you want to compose two `FunctionK`-`~>`-nat trafos `PathOps ~> Free[Fs, ?]` and `Fs ~> IO`? That is: does your desired natural trafo `PathOps ~> IO` somehow *factor through* the `Free[Fs, ?]`-monad?

Comment: Thanks Andrey that was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to write two interpreters `PathOps ~> Free[Fs, ?]`
and `Fs ~> IO`, and then to compose them into a single interpreter `PathOps ~> IO`.

A compilable example follows. Here are all the imports that I used for this example:

```
import cats.~>
import cats.free.Free
import cats.free.Free.liftF
```

Here is a mock-implementation of `IO` and your algebras:

```
// just for this example
type IO[X] = X 
object IO {
  def apply[A](a: A): IO[A] = a
}

sealed trait Fs[A]
case class Ls(path: String) extends Fs[Seq[String]]
case class Cp(from: String, to: String) extends Fs[Unit]
type FreeFs[A] = Free[Fs, A]

def ls(path: String) = Free.liftF(Ls(path))
def cp(from: String, to: String) = Free.liftF(Cp(from, to))
```

This is the interpreter `Fs ~> IO` copied from your code:

```
def fsToIoInterpreter = new (Fs ~> IO) {
  def apply[A](fa: Fs[A]) = fa match {
    case Ls(path) => IO(Seq(path))
    case Cp(from, to) => IO(())
  }
}

sealed trait PathOps[A]
case class SourcePath(template: String) extends PathOps[String]

def sourcePath(template: String) = Free.liftF(SourcePath(template))
```

This is your `for`-comprehension converted into a `PathOps ~> Free[Fs, ?]`-interpreter:

```
val pathToFsInterpreter = new (PathOps ~> FreeFs) {
  def apply[A](p: PathOps[A]): FreeFs[A] = p match {
    case SourcePath(template) => {
      for {
        paths <- ls(template)
      } yield paths.head
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can lift the `Fs ~> IO` into an `Free[Fs, ?] ~> IO` using `Free.foldMap`, and compose it with the `PathOps ~> Free[Fs, ?]`-interpreter using `andThen`:

```
val pathToIo: PathOps ~> IO = 
  pathToFsInterpreter andThen 
  Free.foldMap(fsToIoInterpreter)
```

This gives you an interpreter from `PathOps ~> IO` that consists of two separate layers that can be tested separately.